# HTML <input pattern=''> for song name

Tags: html

I am making a song request system and I have made a request form, but I do not want people to be able to send HTML using <> symbols for example.
Is there any pattern to allow: A-Z,a-z,0-9, ,-. (A to Z, a to z, zero - nine, a space and a dash.)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this your pattern

```
pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\s-]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression.

```
<form>
   <input type="text"  pattern="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[\s]{1}[-]{1}" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I just tried with IE,Firefox and Chrome and it works as expected in those browsers. Can you please add your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ ?